# Websockets and flushing with Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, html, websocket

I am using the Mojolicious::Lite module to run a websockets server to handle the protocol. This is the testing code I am currently using for client:

```
socket.onopen = function(){$.each(proxies, function(){socket.send(this);});}
socket.onmessage = function(response){alert(response);}
```

And the server

```
websocket '/' => sub { 
    my $self = shift;
    $self->on(message => sub {
        my ($self, $message) = @_;
        my @info = split /-/,$message;

        $mech_proxy = WWW::Mechanize->new(timeout=>$info[1], autocheck=>0);
        $self->send(test_proxy($info[0]) => sub{sleep(int(rand(10)))});
    });
};
app->start;
```

Anyhow I thought that this would clearly avoid the need to flush the output, as originally I was actually doing just one send client side and then having the return message sent in a loop on server side; this didn't work because I wouldn't be able to flush the output and would have to wait for the loop to finish. However changing it around didn't help as I still have to wait until the last server side send is done and only then the data is sent to the client.
Do you have any idea how I can get live 'updates' on the processing, i.e. output the server response as it is sent?

EDIT:
I am getting mixed results with `setTimout(socket.send(this),1000)`. What I figured is that probably in order to get the data flushed, new data must be sent only after the prior data has been processed and fully written on the server side. If this proves in fact right, it should be possible to write the client side so it only sends new data after it has received results from the previous data sent; this will achieve the effect of getting the desired 'live' updates.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry for the harsh comment and sorry for bugging you again, but just a few explanations I feel obliged. Why to create global variables out of POST? You don't actually need them, but rather already an SQL string. So, you can create the SQL query directly.  There is a pitfall too, fieldnames have to be whitelisted (or there can be something like user_role=admin in the POST), but if you have an array of field names(matching HTML form fields), you can iterate over it and create a query, escaping and *quoting* fields. The latter is a thing of the high importance - escaping alone helps nothing.

Comment: No worries, it had a reason to it. I deleted the post because yes you were right on the things posted and honest to say I did not want to argue about it. I have used the approach in very large applications a) because it was easily scalable and b) it helped me to enforce correct variable naming conventions (normally the loop would include switch to treat different data types in certain way, adding prefixes, filtering and sorting etc). As for SQL usage of stored procedures is always preferred, so those considerations are not really relevant.

Comment: But to enforce whatever naming convention you need an array with all the allowed variable names whitelisted anyway, don't you? But in the snippet you posted you were using $_POST only, so, there was no way to control names coming from the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK sorted it out, it was as said above new data must be sent only after receiving back response (code below). Also one note, surprisingly this way is actually faster than doing it with the jquery loop.

```
socket.onopen = function(){
    socket.send(proxies[0]+'-'+timeout);
    proxies.splice(0,1);
}

socket.onmessage = function(response){
    if (proxies.length > 0) {
        socket.send(proxies[0]+'-'+timeout);
        proxies.splice(0,1);
    }
document.write(response.data);
}
```